# connect MyEtherWallet to testnet

Tags: testnets, myetherwallet

I configured a private testnet according this guide:

```
https://media.consensys.net/how-to-build-a-private-ethereum-blockchain-fbf3904f337
```

Now I would like to connect my testnet to MyEtherWallet which is running on my local computer. If I try to connect with the testnet I get the following error message:

```
Could not connect to the node. Please refresh the page, or see the help page for more troubleshooting suggestions.
```

What do I have to do in order to connect to my tesnet?

Comment: try to inspect the page and read the error displayed in the console

Comment: try this guide https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet/issues/226

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON-RPC API endpoint must be set up to allow access not only from `localhost` but from the wider public network too. If your `rpcaddr` flag is set to `localhost`, then the external MyEtherWallet site cannot connect to it. Setting `rpcaddr` to `0.0.0.0` will open it up to all public access, but then make sure you know what you're doing if you also are storing Ether in that node's wallet; it's now publicly-accessible, making it easier to lose your funds there.

[Related question: How can I expose Geth's RPC server to external connections?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3163/how-can-i-expose-geths-rpc-server-to-external-connections)