# Access ethereum client from remote machine

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp, testrpc

I need to access ethereum client  setup on remote hosted machine (google cloud ). How can I access the client from the web browser of my local machine ?
Current installations on my machine

> user@instance-1:~$ lsb_release -a
>
> No LSB modules are available.
>
> Distributor ID: Ubuntu
>
> Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
>
> Release:        16.04
>
> Codename:       xenial
>
> user@instance-1:~$
>
> user@instance-1:~$ node -v
>
> v6.12.3
>
> user@instance-1:~$ npm -v
>
> 3.10.10
>
> user@instance-1:~$ ganache-cli -version
>
> Ganache CLI v6.0.3 (ganache-core: 2.0.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this via a Digital Ocean droplet where I run Parity as the client and ssh tunnel into the UI. It's actually quite simple and the instructions can be found here-- https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Wallet-Remote-Access

Don't forget to generate a new token on the Parity command line each time you need to access the UI from your local browser, this gave me quite a headache when I was forgetting to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use SSH tunnel (relative straightforward) or set up a Nginx web server with password protection.

SSH port forward instructions:

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3209/620

Nginx proxy instructions:

https://tokenmarket.net/news/technology/protecting-ethereum-json-rpc-api-with-password/