# How to prevent to change coinbase address for geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, console, coinbase

I am trying to get test ether on ropsten testnet, so I set coinbase address like

```
miner.setEtherbase("0xxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
```

and started to mine from my node,

```
miner.start(4);
```

But someone changed the coinbase address of my node, after few days later, the address is

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xd9ee4d08a86b430544254ff95e32aa6fcc1d3163

But I have to open my RPC end point to use for other team members. So is there any other way to prevent to change my node coinbase address??

Comment: may this answer is what you looking for : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3163/how-can-i-expose-geths-rpc-server-to-external-connections

Comment: sounds like you have exposed your RPC to external connections?

How is your node configured?

Answer (score 0):

In geth you can restrict IPs that can connect to your node with the command line parameter `--netrestrict`.

```
--netrestrict value   Restricts network communication to the given IP networks (CIDR masks)
```

If you want more complex filtering capabilities you can use a firewall in front of your node.